# I cant get my interface to work

Tags: c#, interface

This is my first time using interfaces so I imagine I'm doing something dumb.  I have an interface called ILoadable inside ILoadable.cs;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface ILoadable {
    void AssetLoader(); 
}
```

I also have a couple scripts that implements the interface, here's the small one;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InputRebinder : MonoBehaviour, ILoadable {

    string upKey;



    public void AssetLoader(){
        upKey = ",";
    }
}
```

Then I have a script that I want to call all the instances of AssetLoader throughout my game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InterfaceControl : MonoBehaviour {
    ILoadable loader;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        AssetInterface();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void AssetInterface(){

        loader.AssetLoader();
    }
}
```

I want all my assets to load up when the game starts. Assets in this case being links to gameobjects, so I'm essentially running a bunch of gameobject.find~ and I want to be able to summon those at will. Instead of working as advertised I'm getting this error;

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
InterfaceControl.AssetInterface () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/Interfaces/InterfaceControl.cs:18)
InterfaceControl.Awake () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/Interfaces/InterfaceControl.cs:9)
```

Which I know means I need to have an instance of loader in my interfacecontrol script. I think I could probably put in

loader = new InputRebinder(); But I don't want to just call input rebinder I want to call any script that has the ILoadable interface.

'for reference, I was following the instructions on dotnetperls.com in the interfaces section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46283/way-to-get-all-object-with-a-certain-componentscri.html

Here's what you're looking for. You want to find all components of this type in the scene. Since Unity 5 you should be able to find interface in the generic versions of Find* or Get* methods.

You should probably only do this in Awake, Start or some other method that does not run every frame since finding these can be pretty slow.